# after combining more than one javascript files using online Optimizer Finally which name to use?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I used a website template that have 10 different javascript files. So, takes more time to load. 
So, I optimezed and combined all different js files into one using jscompress.com
they given me a single - less size javascript code, but How to use it??
Which name should given to that file So I dont have to change all codes
OR I have to change enire coding according to that filename?

Comment: Name it whatever you want. But yes, you have to replace all references to the 10 original files with a reference to the new, compressed file.

Comment: this is not a programming question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created a new file then you will have to reference it accordingly from either your html/template files.

If you have a project with a great deal of javascript that you want to combine and minify your javascript whilst still being able to update the individual files I would advise using a task manager like grunt or gulp and use their concat, uglify and watch plugins. This will allow you to write a task to watch all your javascript files and compile a new minified js bundle when the individual files are updated.

**Grunt**
 - http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

**Gulp**
 - http://gulpjs.com/